# Run Lambda function with same permissions as user invoking API Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have the following setup:

REST API Gateway containing one endpoint with a proxy Lambda integration and secured using the `AWS_IAM` authorizer. End users retrieve temporary AWS credentials from a `Cognito Identity Pool` in exchange for tokens retrieved from a `Cognito User Pool` and then call the API using these credentials.

When users call the API Gateway, I want the invoked lambda function to run with the same permissions as the invoking user. For example, if the user only has the permission to read items from DynamoDB with a PK of `CUSTOMER1234`, I want the lambda function to also only have that permission. Different users will have different permissions so I can't "hard-code" that into my Lambda permissions.

This seems like a fairly common use case, but I was unable to find any documentation on how to achieve something like this.

One possibility would be to send the AWS credentials (i.e. access key and secret key) of the user with every request and then construct a new session using these credentials in the Lambda, but this probably is a terrible idea (it also increases function runtime by 5x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a good idea to send AWS credentials over the network, as there is the chance that they could be intercepted by an attacker and used to access your resources until they expired.

It could be possible to use the JWT from your Cognito User Pool to get the AWS credentials *in the lambda function* e.g. using:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: {
        'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': 'ID_TOKEN'
    }
});
```

This would mean that your lambda's API calls would run using the role mapped to in your identity pool, and you could use the LeadingKeys condition to ensure that your web identity could only access their own data:

```
"Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
    }
}
```

However, this would add processing time because you are making extra API calls (`CognitoIdentityCredentials()` makes 2 API calls behind the scenes) on *every* request to get the credentials. Plus, you couldn't use the AWS_IAM authorization on your API Gateway method because you won't have got the credentials yet. So you are then talking about having a two authorization setups. One to allow your web identity to call the API Gateway method, and a second for your Lambda function to run as your user.

So perhaps your choices are:

*Make your API calls direct from your client*

Instead of going via API Gateway, you could make the DynamoDB API calls directly from the client. This would work well with your Identity Pool setup, as you can make the `CognitoIdentityCredentials()` call just once when the user logs in to get the AWS credentials. The subsequent DynamoDB calls would then be made with your user permissions and you could use the LeadingKeys condition to ensure that your user only accesses their own data.

*Accept that your lambda function will always run with the same execution role*

If you want to use API Gateway backed with Lambda, then you could just accept that you will use Lambda or Cognito Authorizers to authorize your users have permissions to execute the API method, and then some further *application-level* authorization in the Lambda function to ensure they only call their own partition space. In fact, this way you might not need the Identity Pool, but rather just use the `sub` claim from the User Pool JWT token. After all, you will have validated the JWT containing the `sub` hasn't been tampered with, and that it was issued by the correct user pool and application client, so you can trust its contents.

*You could integrate API Gateway directly with DynamoDB*

Depending on your required logic, rather than have your API method backed by a lambda function you could integrate your API Gateway method directly with DynamoDB [as shown in this amazon tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/). Again, you would use the `sub` from the validated JWT as the partition key to enforce the correct data access.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thank you for taking the time! I ultimately decided for the application-level authorization in my lambda functions. Calling Dynamo directly from the client would not allow me to do things like data validation and throttling, which i definitely need. Integrating API Gateway with Dynamo is an interesting approach however, I'll look into it!